# Pressing enter after typing in Instagram Searchbox Python

Tags: python, selenium, key, instagram, bots

I'm trying to type in a username in the Instagram searchbox and then press enter to go to this exact page. But it doensn't work. It fills out the name but doenst press enter? Somebody have any clue?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aig1k.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may work better in seperate lines.

```
search_box.send_keys('persons_username')
time.sleep(.5)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Also, things get much easier if you create variables for different elements.